# OpenCV 2.4.4 and QT5

Tags: opencv, qt5

Is the new OpenCV version supporting QT5 or is still using QT4?

I was looking in the [OpenCV changelog](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog) to check if the code is compatible with QT5 but could not find any information.

Did someone compiled OpenCV with QT5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, OpenCV 2.4.4 doesn't support Qt 5 yet.

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15268560/176769) shows how to build OpenCV 2.4.3 with Qt 5. I believe you'll need to do minor changes to make it work for 2.4.4.

Comment: @karlphilip Are you sure that OpenCv 2.4.4 does not work with Qt 5? I am saying because I once tried and it did no problem. However I generally work in OpenCv 2.4.3 in my machine and have not installed 2.4.4 yet.

Comment: Yes I am sure of that. By the way I did not build from the OpenCv source ( using cmake and enabling qt support, tbb support blah blah). I downloaded OpenCv 2.4.4 , extracted it and integrated the pre built libraries with my Qt creator and it ran successfully.

Comment: Now (from version 2.4.6) OpenCv is trying to use QT 5 by default (only if specify to use QT of course). For me it was a problem, because i was trying to build opencv with QT 4, but commenting lines 18-32 in cmake\OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake solved my problem. I know it's not perfect solution and propably there is a better solution for that problem.