# 'mingw32-make' is not recognized in cmd while integrate Qt 5.0.2 and OpenCV 2.4.4 with CMAKE 2.8.10.2 in Windows 7

Tags: opencv, cmake, qt5, mingw32

I was installing QT5 and OpenCV 2.4.4 with CMAKE 2.8.10.2..

I was following the instruction from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919186/qt-creator-5-0-1-with-opencv-2-3-4-on-windows/15268560#15268560) and [here](http://www.slideshare.net/luigidr/installing-opencv-242-with-qt) .
The problem is, when I want to compile the OpenCV library with cmd, 'mingw32-make' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
I don't know how to react, I've follow the instruction step by step..

Thanks for your answers :)

===============================

This question has been answered :) 
the answer is I didn't put the path contains mingw32-make.exe (Qt5.0.2\Tools\MinGW\bin) to system variable. different version different path, made me confuse.

So, if you want to integrate Qt 5.0.2 and OpenCV 2.4.4 with CMAKE 2.8.10.2 in Windows 7, use instructions from two links that I mention it above, it works! Thanks:)

Comment: That means that none of the directories you put in your `PATH` contains `mingw32-make.exe`. You should search whether you have it somewhere and put its directory into your path. If you don't have it but have `make.exe`, rename it to `mingw32-make.exe` and put its directory into your path.

Comment: yeah, you are right, I forgot to put the path contains mingw32-make.exe to system variable, because of the tutorials didn't mention it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

In start menu you can find pre-configured environment variable command prompt link for Qt MinGW. If you are using `Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.7, 650 MB)` you may find something like `Qt 5.0.2 for Desktop (MinGW 4.7)`. Use it for your command. Please make sure you are using mingw32 version of Qt otherwise the command you are looking for is `nmake`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using mingw32 version of Qt. Thank you for answering my question :)

Comment: You are welcome! You should accept the answer if you think I've answered it correctly.