# OpenCV 2.4.6 with QT 5.1.0 Errors

Tags: qt, opencv

I am trying to get OpenCv2.4.6 to work with QT5.1.0
I've followed  this Guide so far [Qt creator 5.0.1 with OpenCv 2.3.4 on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919186/qt-creator-5-0-1-with-opencv-2-3-4-on-windows/15268560#15268560)

Unfortunatly after finishing trying out the sample Application(Display an Image using OpenCv in the QtCreator I get these Errors:

```
[Project-Path]\main.o:-1: In function `main':
[Project-Path]\main.cpp:8: error: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
[Project-Path]\main.cpp:9: error: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
[Project-Path]\main.cpp:10: error: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
[Project-Path]\main.cpp:10: error: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
[Project-Path]\main.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
[Project Build Path Desktop Debug]\debug\main.o:-1: In function `ZN2cv3MatD1Ev':
   [OpenCV/Install/include]\opencv2\core\mat.hpp:278: error: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
[Project Build Path Desktop Debug]\debug\main.o:-1: In function `ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv':
   [OpenCV/Install/include]\opencv2\core\mat.hpp:367: error: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the "[]" Paths are my formatting and supposed to help keep track .

main.cpp

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>


using namespace cv;
int main() {
        // read an image
        Mat image = imread("img.jpg");
        namedWindow("My Image");
        imshow("My Image", image);
        waitKey(5000);

        return 1;
}
```

myFirstOpenCVProject.pro

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = myFirstOpenCVProject
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += C:/qt/OpenCV246_bin/install/include
LIBS += -LC:/qt/OpenCV246_bin/install/lib/lopencv_core246.dll
LIBS += -LC:/qt/OpenCV246_bin/install/lib/lopencv_highgui246.dll
LIBS += -LC:/qt/OpenCV246_bin/install/lib/lopencv_imgproc246.dll
LIBS += -LC:/qt/OpenCV246_bin/install/lib/lopencv_features2d246.dll
LIBS += -LC:/qt/OpenCV246_bin/install/lib/lopencv_calib3d246.dll
```

Can you help me resolve this?
I can't find any solutions that apply to my case ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-L` is to add directories to the search path. The actual libs are added via `-l`. The correct line would be:

```
LIBS += -LC:/qt/OpenCV246_bin/install/lib -llopencv_core246 -llopencv_highgui246 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the static libs of opencv:

```
opencv_core246.lib
opencv_highgui246.lib
opencv_video246.lib
opencv_ml26d.lib
opencv_legacy246.lib
opencv_imgproc246.lib
opencv_whatever.lib
```

Don t know the pro commands very well. Maybe something like:

```
LIBS +=  -Lc:/blabla/opencv_imgproc246.lib
```